# Value only gets set when using alert()

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-post, jquery

So I have the code below. Holder1/Holder2 are just there to see if setting the values to a variable works

```
jQuery.each(substr, function() {
 if ($('div#'+this+' div.widgetcontent iframe').attr("src")!=undefined) {
    //alert('Widget iFrame: '+$('div#'+this+' div.widgetcontent iframe').attr("src"));
    //alert('Report URL: '+$('div#'+this+' div.widgetcontent iframe').contents().find('iframe').attr("src"));
    var holder1 = 'Widget iFrame: '+$('div#'+this+' div.widgetcontent iframe').attr("src");
    var holder2 = 'Report URL: '+$('div#'+this+' div.widgetcontent iframe').contents().find('iframe').attr("src");
    $.post("functions/process.asp", 
    { 
        widget: $('div#'+this+' div.widgetcontent iframe').attr("src"), 
        iframe: $('div#'+this+' div.widgetcontent iframe').contents().find('iframe').attr("src")
    } 
    , function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
     }
);
}
```

However the iframe value is not posted. However instead of using holder1/holder2, if I were to use the following instead, it all works

```
alert('Widget iFrame: '+$('div#'+this+' div.widgetcontent iframe').attr("src"));
alert('Report URL: '+$('div#'+this+' div.widgetcontent iframe').contents().find('iframe').attr("src"));
```

Obviously I don't want it alerting each time so was wondering what was happening?

I've basically implemented a dashboard where people can add widgets and then move them up or down. There is one there by default. If I add another (becomes second) and then move it to the first position, it gives a blank value. If I move it back to second, it works.

[EDIT]

In fact, if I just use `alert('');` then it works just fine!!!

Comment: What are the holders actually for ? I don't see you using them in your code.

Comment: It works if I comment the holders and uncomment the alerts which is the confusing bit for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a delay straight after `stop: function(event, ui) {` of 1 second which seems to sort it

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is that you use "this" in the ajax-request. try to save it to a variable before and use it

```
jQuery.each(substr, function() {
var myobject=this;
        if ($('div#'+myobject+' div.widgetcontent iframe').attr("src")!=undefined) {
            var holder1 = 'Widget iFrame: '+$('div#'+myobject+' div.widgetcontent iframe').attr("src");
            var holder2 = 'Report URL: '+$('div#'+myobject+' div.widgetcontent iframe').contents().find('iframe').attr("src");

            $.post("functions/process.asp", 
            { 
            widget: $('div#'+myobject+' div.widgetcontent iframe').attr("src"), 
            iframe: $('div#'+myobject+' div.widgetcontent iframe').contents().find('iframe').attr("src")
            } 
            , function(data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
             }
             );
        }
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. When I change the widget/iframe to `widget: holder1, iframe: holder2` I get the message that holder 2 is undefined.

Comment: can you post your HTML, i think it's possible that your jquery selector is the problem

Comment: It gets the SRC of the iFrame fine so not sure why it's not getting the SRC of the iFrame within that iFrame?!?   `<div id="100" title="Referrals Trends">
    <div class="widgetcontent">
      <iframe src="widgets/widget1_iframe.html" style="width:100%; border:none;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>` If I leave the alerts in, it works just fine!!!